# ¿Cómo determinar donde está el valor más cercano a cero en un DataFrame?

Tags: python

tengo una duda en Python 2. Teniendo un DataFrame compuesta por una única columna, ¿cómo puedo determinar cuál es el valor más cercano a cero, independiente si es negativo o no? Quisiera saber si existe algún método en pandas que pueda determinar esto, para no tener que confeccionar un algoritmo que lo haga. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera ademas de agregar el código que has intentado hasta ahora. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma general de abordar el problema es calcular el valor absoluto de la columna, ordenarla y obtener el menor valor. Esto es muy simple de hacer usando el método `abs` e `idxmin` de las series:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({"col": (4, 7, 8, 5, -3, 21, 13)})

value = 12
idx = (df["col"] - value).abs().idxmin()
nearest = df["col"].loc[idx]
```

> ```
> >>> df
>    col
> 0    4
> 1    7
> 2    8
> 3    5
> 4   -3
> 5   21
> 6   13
> >>> idx
> 6
> >>> nearest
> 13
> ```

Como buscas el valor más próximo a 0 basta con:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({"col": (4, 7, 8, 5, -3, 21, 13)})


idx = df["col"].abs().idxmin()
nearest = df["col"].loc[idx]
```

> ```
> >>> idx
> 4
> >>> nearest
> -3
> ```

Comment: Muchas gracias FJSevilla!